ContextCompat.registerReceiver - "Must be one or more of values" error
I'm trying to migrate my app to API 34, and in the process, I must add flags when registering a Broadcast Receiver.
However, I'm having an error hint saying that the flag I added is incorrect, and must be in a list of values, even though that's exactly what I did...
So, when doing this:
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, receiver, intentFilter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
I have the error message: Must be one or more of: androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS, androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED, androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
I have the following values: compileSdk 34; minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 34
How can I get rid of this message?

I'm receiving this same error when trying to register a receiver using ContextCompat.registerReceiver with ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED. I have the necessary dependencies but I'm still receiving the error... I added a @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") to the method to remove the error and my application runs fine - I just don't want to suppress lint warnings in case there actually is a problem.
